# How do I get a prediction out of a h5 with tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, prediction

So I'm not able to figure out how to get a propability in % or a label out of this matrix.

Story behind this model:

-The model is supposed to detect if a comment(/text) should be deleted or not.

-labels are True or False

Is there any way to get it work or how i can transform that vector?

My Code:

```
model = models.load_model(h5_model)
string = "sh!t"
x_test = string.lower()
tok = text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, lower=True)
tok.fit_on_texts(list(x_test))
x_test = tok.texts_to_sequences(x_test)
text_preprocessing_for_single_comments(string)
prediction = model.predict(to_predict)
print(prediction)

>>[[0.5180945 ][0.5354299 ][0.47555092] [0.5636673]]
```

Answer (score 0):

predictions are class probabilities. For converting in percentage :

```
prediction *= 100
```

If 1 means True and 0 means False, then a probability above 0.5 would mean True and below it would be false.

```
prediction = np.round( prediction )
# Get an array of 0s and 1s
class = np.argmax( prediction )
```